# Different ways to log in to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, authentication

I'm trying to log in to a mariaDB database which is (at least the vendor of the product that it was installed for tells so) "protected" by SSL.

I tried several tools but none of them works fully.

- MySQL Workbench exits silently when I try to connect but when I choose the "reverse engineering" menu entry it is able to extract and display the schema.
- HeidiSQL fails with `Access denied for user 'username'@'fqdn.of.my.computer' (using password: YES)`
- dBeaver shows the same: `Access denied for user 'username'@'fqdn.of.my.computer' (using password: YES)`
- Database Workbench fails with the same error as the others: `Access denied for user 'username'@'fqdn.of.my.computer' (using password: YES)`

I am sure that the credentials are typed correctly because I copy them from a notepad window and they work with MySQL Workbench.
All tools are run with the current version available, community or free and not paid)

Are there different ways to authenticate with a MariaDB server ? Basically MySQL Workbench seems to work the best, but because it fails silently with a "full" connection this is also not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to authenticate, but you have to specify this per database user. Before MariaDB 10.4 each user could only use one authentication method. You can change the authentication method for a user if you can log in as the `root` or other sufficiently privileged user. Use the `ALTER USER` statement if you're on MariaDB 10.2+, otherwise use `UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '...' WHERE user = 'the_user' AND host = 'the_host';`.

Authentication is done by authentication plugins. Run e.g. this to see which plugins you currently use for your database users:

```
SELECT user, host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

Some common authentication plugins are `mysql_native_password` and `unix_socket`. The former requires a password and works over TCP whereas the latter works over the MariaDB socket file (by default it's at `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` in Linux) and doesn't require a password, but it assumes your OS user has the same name as your database user, and obviously only works if you're on the same host as the MariaDB server. Perhaps this is something you could try to avoid SSL?

**Relevant MariaDB Knowledgebase documentation**

- [ALTER USER - authentication options](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/#authentication-options)
- [Pluggable Authentication Overview](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pluggable-authentication-overview/)
- [Authentication Plugin - Unix Socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/)
- [Authentication from MariaDB 10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-from-mariadb-104/)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I run these commands when I can't create a connection? I am not on the same host.  What confuses me the most is that one of these connections can be established. How can I find out why it works for the reverse engineering ?

Comment: @Marged - Are you able to `ssh` to the MariaDB host? If so, you don't need these tools to create a connection. You can use the MariaDB command-line client, which is called `mysql`. It will presumably be installed on the host already.

Comment: SSH can work but we need to provide access for business staff which mustn't SSH and needs a Windows GUI tool. Btw: SSH tunnels are blocked at our site

Comment: @Marged I think in your case maybe you can use SSH and the `mysql` client to help diagnose your problem. I think you just need to sort out what appears to be an SSL-related problem with the connections. In order to enable SSL (well TLS) on the client side, you probably want to read the documentation on this page: [Securing Connections for Client and Server](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/).